# How do you put a user's name or ID in the URL on a specific page [WordPress]

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I'm new here and complex things in Wordpress still confuse me as I am learning. I am trying to relay a logged in user's ID or username to the URL when on a specific page (the dashboard page). I have tried many plugins that allow you to change parameters of general page taxonomy and slugs but I didn't get anywhere with that at all. It's probably a simple answer, but I don't know how to even approach it. I did alot of Google searches, but all the results keep referring to Wordpress's %author% tag, which IS NOT what I want because it only generates the person who created the page, instead of the currently logged in user.

If anyone can help me I'd be really appreciative. FYI: I am not super skilled in PHP or much back-end as I am more into Front End designing. So if any answers revolve around that please provide a "kindergarten" explanation/answer for me

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". You're asking us to write a tutorial, however we don't know your expertise level so that would amount to an entire text book.

Answer (score 0):

All you need here is [wp_get_current_user()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user).

```
<?php

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    $username = $current_user->user_login;
    $user_ID = $current_user->ID;

    echo "Welcome $username, your ID is $user_ID";

?>
```

About how to edit your "dashboard page", you need first to find the [page template file](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) and then edit the code inside it.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So I wasn't 100% sure where to put this code but I'm assuming it needs to go into my pages.php files under my /wp-content/themes/themename. In which case my theme is OceanWP so I put the code at the top of the pages.php I'm not entirely sure If that's what I was suppose to do with that, because now it just says what the Echo is supposed to say at the bottom of my header on each page, but doesn't put any fields in the URL at all.